# After certain test case, heap gets corrupt

Tags: c, dynamic, memory-leaks

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
int *starting_time = NULL;
int *frequency_time = NULL;
int *duration_time = NULL;
int *toured_cities = NULL;


int check(int t,int i,int s, int a){
    int k; int p=starting_time[i];
    while (1){
        k= p+frequency_time[i];
        if (k>a) return p;
        else if ((k-t)>=s) return k;
        p=k;
    }
}

void sight_seeing(){
    int c,s,a; int size=4;
    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d",&c,&s,&a);
    starting_time=(int *)realloc(starting_time,size*sizeof(int));
    frequency_time=(int *)realloc(frequency_time,size*sizeof(int));
    duration_time=(int *)realloc(duration_time,size*sizeof(int));
    toured_cities = (int *)realloc(toured_cities,size*sizeof (int));

    for (int i=1;i<c;i++){
        scanf("%d",&starting_time[i]);
        scanf("%d",&frequency_time[i]);
        scanf("%d",&duration_time[i]);
        toured_cities[i]=0;
    }    
    int t = 0;int x = 0;int i=1;int k;bool q;
    while (t<a){
        if (i==c) break;
        if ((starting_time[i]-t)>=s) {
            k=starting_time[i]; 
            x++;
        }
        else{
            k = check(t,i,s,a);
            if ((k+duration_time[i])<a) x++;
            else if ((k+duration_time[i])==a)
            {
                if (i<c-1) k=starting_time[i];
            }
        }
        t=k+duration_time[i];
        if (t>a) toured_cities[i]=0;
        else toured_cities[i]=1;
        i++;
    }
    for (int i=1;i<c;i++){
        if (toured_cities[i]==1) q=1;
        else q=0;
    }
    if (q==1 && x>=0) printf("The maximum sightseeing possible %d \n",x);
    else printf("\nSightseeing is not Impossible\n");
    starting_time = (int *)realloc(starting_time,0);
    frequency_time = (int *)realloc(frequency_time, 0);
    duration_time = (int *)realloc(duration_time,0);
    toured_cities = (int *)realloc(toured_cities,0);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n--){
        sight_seeing();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code.
This code is passing for test cases less than 10.
But for test cases 100.
I am getting this error.

```
          *** Error in `./prog': free(): invalid next size (fast): 
           0x00002b2db77fac20 ***
            ======= Backtrace: =========
           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bcb)[0x2b2db738dbcb]
           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76f96)[0x2b2db7393f96]
           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7778e)[0x2b2db739478e]
           ./prog(+0xcd3)[0x2b2db643acd3]
           ./prog(+0x875)[0x2b2db643a875]
           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)
           [0x2b2db733d2b1]
           ./prog(+0x93a)[0x2b2db643a93a]
            ======= Memory map: ========
           2b2db643a000-2b2db643b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 17031175                   
            /home/S5BAtg/prog
            2b2db643b000-2b2db643f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  
              2b2db6448000-2b2db644d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0    
              2b2db663b000-2b2db663c000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 17031175                   
            /home/S5BAtg/prog  
            2b2db663c000-2b2db663d000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 17031175                   
            /home/S5BAtg/prog
```

This is the error , I am receiving.
Also, please help me with the complexity analysis of the code.

Comment: This is all `C` code.  In `C++`, `std::vector` is used.

Comment: @Paul Despite `#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - This is not valid C code. `int *starting_time = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` is an invalid initialization. You cannot initialize statics with anything other than constant expressions in C. I however agree that it's way to a C-ish style for coding. Not idiomatic C++ at all.

Comment: All the arrays are reallocated with length of 5 (not c) that is why it corrupts the memory.

Comment: @ÖöTiib why will I use c? I require the length of the array to be 5.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie here 1 is used as a constant. This is a pointer allocated a memory. Later i am reallocating more space and making it a array

Comment: Off the top of my head 1. Why are you using global variables. 2. Why are you casting `malloc` - google why this is bad. 3.Each line of code should just do one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is this:

- You reallocate the arrays for 5 entries only.  Once you read a value of `6` for `c`, you access and modify entries beyond the end of these arrays.

There are many other problems:

- You cannot initialize global objects from runtime expressions in C: `int *starting_time = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` is invalid. Indeed you must compile this code as C++ give the header file `<cstdlib>`. Note that your code would work the same if you just initialized these array pointers to `NULL` or left them uninitialized and global.
- global variables with short names like `int c,s,a;` is considered bad style and error prone.  You should make all these variables local in the `sight_seeing()` function.
- arrays are zero based in C, the loop `for (int i=1;i<c;i++)` only iterates `c-1` times, which is probably not intended.
- There is a logic error in the loop used to verify if the complete tour can be completed: `q` is set for each city, hence its value only reflects whether the last city can be visited.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check(int t, int i, int a, int s, int *starting_time, int *frequency_time) {
    int k;
    int p = starting_time[i];
    while (1) {
        k = p + frequency_time[i];
        if (k > a)
            return p;
        else
        if (k - t >= s)
            return k;
        p = k;
    }
}

void sight_seeing(void) {
    int c, s, a;

    if (scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &c, &s, &a) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int *starting_time = (int*)calloc(c, sizeof(int));
    int *frequency_time = (int*)calloc(c, sizeof(int));
    int *duration_time = (int*)calloc(c, sizeof(int));
    int *toured_cities = (int*)calloc(c, sizeof(int));

    if (!starting_time || !frequency_time || !duration_time || !toured_cities) {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d%d%d", &starting_time[i], &frequency_time[i], &duration_time[i]) != 3) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }    
    int t = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int i, k;
    bool q;

    for (i = 0; i < c && t < a; i++) {
        if (starting_time[i] - t >= s) {
            k = starting_time[i]; 
            x++;
        } else {
            k = check(t, i, a, s, starting_time, frequency_time);
            if (k + duration_time[i] < a)
                x++;
            else
            if (k + duration_time[i] == a) {
                if (i < c - 1)
                   k = starting_time[i];
            }
        }
        t = k + duration_time[i];
        if (t > a)
            toured_cities[i] = 0;
        else
            toured_cities[i] = 1;
    }
    q = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (toured_cities[i] == 0) {
            q = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (q == 1 && x >= 0)
        printf("The maximum sightseeing possible %d \n", x);
    else
        printf("\nSightseeing is not Impossible\n");  // not sure what you mean?

    free(starting_time);
    free(frequency_time);
    free(duration_time);
    free(toured_cities);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        while (n-- >0) {
            sight_seeing();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir, i have to take entries from 1 to c-1. That i am aware of.

Comment: @AnirudhaBhaskar: what is the meaning of the 3 numbers you read at the start of `sight_seeing()`? It does not make much sense to specify that the user type the number of cities+1.

Comment: Sir, suppose the value of c is 4. so, we have to cover 4 cities and starting, frequency and duration time of 3 cities are given. s stands for sight_Seeing time and a stands for arrival_time

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. the code is running smoothly and all heap blocks freed.

Comment: Sir, my bad. That small logic mistake where I wrongly initialised the size of the array. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AnirudhaBhaskar: There are other *small logic mistakes* worth taking care of ;-)